# What is the difference between attributes and properties when using in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, frontend

Attributes vs. Properties

The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes. How can I know the difference between attribute and property when using them?

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: I think prop is better used to get state of elements

Comment: Thank you. There is a link addressed which explains me the answer which I am looking for.